# How to make MSBUILD resolve System.Action<T1,T2> correctly?

Tags: c#, assemblies, msbuild-4.0

My projects build fine in Visual Studio and also using MSBUILD on my machine.
On the build agent however if I run MSBUILD I get the error below.
I have already tried to specify a target framework of 4.0 but without success.
Any other ideas?

```
"c:\Test\Test.csproj" (default target) (6) ->
(CoreCompile target) ->
  ItemSearchDelegate.cs(17,10): error CS0433: The type 'System.Action<T1,T2>' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\
Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.
dll'
```

What I find most interesting: some lines above that error from MSBUILD, I see:

```
 CSC : warning CS1685: The predefined type 'System.Action' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll'
```

So it decides to use v4 just to complain a second later?

All I do is: open the command line at the location of the .CSPROJ file and run "msbuild". Nothing fancy.

Comment: is .net 4.0 installed on the build agent machine? What about on your machine?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yep, installed on both. I have now also added a HintPath that points directly to the 4.0 version. Still same error.

Comment: (Is this using TFS build? Or another build system?) - it would be useful if you could obtain the entire command line that your build system is executing.

Comment: The message is accurate, that type indeed exists in both those assemblies.  There's something seriously messed up about the build machine configuration.  It uses assembly references from both c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework *and* the GAC.  That's completely inappropriate, especially so for .NET 4 projects.  Reference assemblies must come from c:\program files\assembly references.  I can't guess how you break msbuild like that.